# Как подвинуть картинку в ссылке , не трогая текст?

Tags: html, css

Просто картинку сдвинуть на `21px` вбок.

Если двигает с помощью `margin`, то все двигается.

Данную штуку сделал с помощью обычной ссылки , где текст и картинка.

Буду очень признателен за ответ и помощь!

```css
.search {
  margin-left: 40px;
  width: 140px;
  height: 38px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-style: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  color: #4b4e5f;
  font-family: MuseoSansCyrl, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="search">Поиск<img src="7.png" alt="search"></a>
```

[image: То, что не получается]

Answer (score 1):

В наше время когда уже есть iphone smartphon's и прочие устройства которые по разному отображают pixel уже не актуально ставить для input какие то изображения

Я воспользовался бесплатным векторным шрифтом [fomt-awesome](http://fontawesome.ru) которые при нужде не обязательно скачивать а лишь выставить ссылку на него в head как в моём примере, я ссылку на него взял из хранилища [cdn](https://cdnjs.com) скопировал от туда ссылку и вставил для примера сюда..

смотрим Дэмо:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.item {
  margin: 10px;
}

p {
  width: 174px;
  position: relative;
}

p input {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 4px 0;
}

p i.fa {
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="item">
  <form action="">
    <p>
      <input type="search">
      <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
    </p>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Наверное самый простой и понятный способ.

```css
.search {
  margin-left: 40px;
  width: 140px;
  height: 38px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-style: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  color: #4b4e5f;
  font-family: MuseoSansCyrl, sans-serif;
}
.search img {
    margin-left: 21px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="search">Поиск<img src="7.png" alt="search"></a>
```